# Should I separate Redis from the webserver if I would like to have my Laravel application under a Load Balancer?

Tags: laravel, redis, load-balancing

I am wondering, if in the future I would like to handle high volume traffic by having my Laravel application under a Load Balancer. The process will be as follow?

1 Load balancer to distribute traffic into:

2 VPS. Each one of these, with an identical Laravel application.

Each web server can connect with:
1 VPS for MYSQL

And here is my doubt, should I also separate Redis such as 1 VPS for Redis and maintaining my Jobs with Laravel Queues?

Or should Redis & Laravel Queues daemon still be on each one of the 2 identical web servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the better way is to have the redis installed and set up on one of your ECS instances.

After that, you should set your Redis config (`REDIS_HOST,REDIS_PORT and REDIS_PASSWORD`) in the .env to connect that ECS instance, on both ECS instances. So it will become as below:

`A ECS -- A ECS redis service
B ECS -- A ECS redis service`

In this way, you does not have to set up an extra ECS which might cost you more and during the same time you can achieve what you want. A drawback for this method is you might need to set up 2 images for your ECS, one with Redis configured and one without.

Comment: how does this approach make the instance "stateless" and reduce the risk to of "single point of failure" ?

Comment: Thanks @Ersoy. You brought up good points. In this context, I believe we do however have to evaluate the cost and benefits, provided that there are only 2 instances. Setting up independent redis cluster might still have the chance of facing "single point of failure" if the redis cluster is down, but yes, smaller risk. In the proposed method, it is almost similar as creating a dedicated redis cluster to maintain stateless server(which is the reason I mentioned 2 images). Except that we still utilize the redis instance's computing power for app services to reduce cost and etc.

Comment: By separating redis cluster from the application server, you may easily horizontally scale it by adding new replicas(for better availability)  and you should have at least two for cluster and three for sentine. But that's right - you need money/time/know-how to manage it for better scalability. That's the tradeoff.

Comment: Yep, agree with that. Thanks for sharing @Ersoy!